# Get Policies from GPO Object in Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy

How can i get these policies as shown here for example in powershell?
With Get-GPO i can get the Group Policies, but not the Policies inside the group.

[image: Policies (German image)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the actual setting names and values, you need to generate a group policy report:

```
[xml]$report = Get-GPOReport -Name 'My-GPO' -Domain 'contoso.com' -Server 'DC1' -ReportType XML
```

Then you can view the settings, though you may have to hunt around for them all. Here's an example of how I can display some internet explorer policy settings:

```
$report.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.Policy | Where State -eq Enabled | Select Name,State

Name                                                                           State  
----                                                                           -----  
URLs to open on startup                                                        Enabled
Turn off add-on performance notifications                                      Enabled
Turn off suggestions for all user-installed providers                          Enabled
Turn off Compatibility View                                                    Enabled
```

Or you can output the report to a file:

```
Get-GPOReport -All -Domain "sales.contoso.com" -Server "DC1" -ReportType XML -Path "C:\GPOReports\GPOReportsAll.xml"
```

More information about [Get-GPOReport here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gporeport?view=win10-ps)